# Can we find all classes within base R?

Tags: r, class

Is there a way to get all the classes that are defined within base R? My expected output is a character vector containing the class names. Something like this:

```
"character" "factor" "function" "dataframe" "list" ...
```

Background: I made a function that is supposed to be applied to as many classes as possible. I can't explain what I'm doing in detail but consider functions like `str` that as far as I know can be applied to any class. On the other hand, there are functions like `sum` that expect certain input, i.e., numeric input. I want to know all predefined classes so that I can see on what classes my function works and which ones don't.

Comment: A class is nothing more than a string attribute on a object. S3 classes can use anything for a class name. I'm assuming that "base R" also refers to default packages like `stats`, `utils` and `graphics`. There are tons of classes out there. For example `class(as.person("Joe Smith"))`. There's no master list as far as I know. What properties of the object are you looking for?

Comment: "consider functions like `str` that as far as I know can be applied to any class" `str` is an S3 generic. The default method works for all modes. If you want to have it do anything specific for a class, you need to define a method for `str`.

Comment: You could look at the `S3method` entries in the `NAMESPACE` files of the [base packages](https://github.com/wch/r-source/tree/trunk/src/library).

Comment: You may find `.S3_methods_table` helpful.

Comment: That are useful hints. Especially the `.S3_methods_table` from @jay.sf is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Assuming this refers to S3 classes start a fresh session, load any packages you want included and run this:

```
sort(unique(sub(".*?\\.", "", ls(.__S3MethodsTable__.))))
```

**2)** A different approach assuming this refers to package "base" (it can be repeated for other base packages if needed) and S3 classes this finds all names in the base package that have one or more dots in them and then the unique values after the dot giving res1 if there is one dot and res2 if there are two or more dots and not in res1. This is only an approximation so you would have to manually go through these to check which ones actually represent classes.

```
nms <- grep("\\.", ls(asNamespace("base")), value = TRUE)
no_dots <- lengths(gregexpr(".", nms, fixed = TRUE))

res1 <- sort(unique(sub(".*\\.", "", nms[no_dots == 1])))
res2 <- setdiff(sort(unique(sub(".*?\\.", "", nms[no_dots > 1]))), res1)
```

Answer (score -1):

It will become tricky even the function `sum` supports more than you think, also depending on `class` you get an issue on `matrix` or an `array` where you need to use `typeof` as well to see if its content is either `numeric, integer` for example. Also note that `NA` is considered `logical` by default and `NULL` gives the class `NULL`.

Here some examples on different class variables and its behaviour with `sum`

```
a <- 1L
class(a)
[1] "integer"

b <- 1
class(b)
[1] "numeric"

c <- FALSE
class(c)
[1] "logical"

d <- as.factor(1L)
class(d)
[1] "factor"

e <- matrix(1:2)
class(e)
[1] "matrix"
typeof(e)
[1] "integer"

f <- c(1:2)
class(f)
[1] "integer"

g <- NA
class(g)
[1] "logical"

h <- NULL
class(h)
[1] "NULL"

i <- -Inf
class(i)
[1] "numeric"

j <- array(1:2)
class(j)
[1] "array"
typeof(j)
[1] "integer"

class(sum(a, a))
[1] "integer"

class(sum(a, b))
[1] "numeric"

class(sum(b, b))
[1] "numeric"

class(sum(c, c))
[1] "integer"

class(sum(c, a))
[1] "integer"

class(sum(c, b))
[1] "numeric"

class(sum(d + d))
[1] "integer"
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(d, d) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors

class(sum(d, d))
Error in Summary.factor(1L, 1L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

class(sum(e, d))
[1] "integer"

class(sum(e, e))
[1] "integer"

class(sum(f, f))
[1] "integer"

class(sum(g, h))
[1] "integer"

class(sum(h, h))
[1] "integer"

class(sum(i, i))
[1] "numeric"

class(sum(e, j))
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: That is interesting, but unfortunately, my question is not about the `sum` function. I mentioned it just as an example. I've also could have writted `mean`, `sd` and so on. In fact the question is about the predefined classes in base R.

Comment: I agree that it is not an answer to your question but it is relevant especially the class versus the typeof for like an array or matrix of data as well of how functions behave upon them. I rather had posted this in the comments and not as answer but due to its format and length posting above as a comment was not possible.